# How can I set Excel tab color using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, colors, tabs

I had assumed this would be easy, but apparently not. The report I am working on is having some sources graveyarded with runout. That means I need to hide 2/3rds of the sheet and color the hidden tabs red to make it clear which are in use and which are not. So far, I have tried Tab.Color and Tab.ColorIndex in a variety of ways and not found a way.

With full ARGB:

```
System.Drawing.Color clr = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
int index = clr.ToArgb();
int hiddenTabColor = index;
...
worksheet.Tab.Color = hiddenTabColor;
```

Adding System.ComponentModel to use Converter:

```
var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Color));
Color clr = (Color)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF0000");
...
worksheet.Tab.Color = clr;
```

There are a dozen permutations of these that I have tried unsuccessfully. The result is always a tab showing xlAutomatic as black. I have tried every overload of the methods.

The vital information is that this is in Visual Studio 2013 writing to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 (Excel) using Interop.

Comment: What have you tried with `ColorIndex`?

Comment: workbook.Tab.ColorIndex = (ColorIndex)3;  
    workbook.Tab.ColorIndex = (Color)3;  
    workbook.Tab.ColorIndex = (Int32)3;  
    workbook..Tab.ColorIndex = (ColorIndex)Color.Red;  
The error every time with color index is that I need to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQPad, I had no trouble getting this to work:

```
var xl = (Excel.Application) Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
var xls = (Excel.Worksheet)xl.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

xls.Tab.ColorIndex = (Excel.XlColorIndex)3;
xls.Tab.Color = 255;
```

Comment: I didn't use the marshalling class, but here is the setup before the calls:

Comment: I don't see anything?

Comment: My apologies. I am having difficulty with the Markdown. Today is month end and I have been whip-sawed from crisis to crisis all day. Let me try again:

Comment: Excel.Application excel     = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wbExcel      = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
   
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbExcel.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    ....
    worksheet.Tab.ColorIndex = (Excel.XlColorIndex)3;

Comment: I should add that this is legacy code and I am pulling this from a developer too swamped to even say 'yes' 'no'.

Comment: Apparently there is something different in configuration/environment. Using your example results in the the same black tab, but I know your code to be correct from experience. I just couldn't get the cast to do anything different while playing with it. Because of this, I am marking your answer as THE answer and upvoting it. The client will have to like black.

Comment: I copied your code and ran it in LINQPad and it changed the tab color without issue. (I added a `.Visible = true;`.) Could you perhaps move the tab color change up in your logic to see if something else is interacting with it?

Comment: Actually, I cleaned up some useless comments and it worked for all the sheets that were hidden with no code changes. Strange, but I knew your code was correct. I am good to go.